# What's the cause of this kind of tyre damage?

Tags: road-bike, tire, puncture

What's causing this type of damage to the tyre?

It's a 25 x 622 tyre on a 13 x 622 rim.

Tyre is a Schwalbe Active Line K-Guard.

The tyre itself doesn't seem worn.

[image: Tyte]

Comment: What kind of shape is the rim in?  What pressure do you normally run?

Comment: I would guess that the brake pads are rubbing the tire.

Comment: Brake pads rubbing or you’ve been riding on a flat (or extremely under-inflated) tire.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another possible cause is misadjusted rim brakes where the brake pad makes contact with the tire's sidewall.

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether the damage runs all around the side-wall at the same distance from the rim as well as the position of the brake pads relative to rim and tyre.

Comment: I think, this is the correct answer because the damage is very close to the bead, exactly where brake pad damage is to be expected. If the tire were run flat, the damage would be higher up in the picture, just below the yellow line.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the cords holding the body of the tire to the bead have torn.  Overinflation, hitting a rock, curb, or other obstacle, running the tire at too low a pressure can cause such damage.  I'm sure there are a host of other reasons as well.

It's also possible this tire was defective from the start.  Hard to say at this point.